# Looking for a high resolution image of a 2004 Cannondale Scalpel 900 Black XC Bike

Tags: cannondale

I'm looking for a high resolution image of the 2004 Cannondale Scalpel 900 Black bike. Preferably with a Lefty fork. It looks like this:

[image]

This is the highest resolution image I can find, 640x371 (but not even with the Left fork) but I would like one that is much more detailed. There used to be one image online but it is no longer available.

I'm needing this image for a small publication I'm doing on older bikes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Google image search and/or an e-mail to Cannondale seem like your best options. You might also try the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not a question about cycling that will benefit other users of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Try Google Image search [based on your image](https://www.google.ca/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivs0CoKkGCv-olfqChiwh98SEDySUU2daCMyX8lulJhlpNfsj6kpk1Gsdt_1fXwXq20qZTE9vV7cXinxrQF-enco4JZ7JQx3OTZpQ6L5WeOF60gvqwgzPbSQz2zaJzS10Qd5apU9ajIIlGaDtn5ejamYGFCZ4mEY5TI_1si3ijeQDpMKE2toeVn4SPpeUHyDXUnk1P7p9d006N0X2mt44F0WtjDeBtbYMKOaVzp9YJJhvWRpcYeED1YyzGNsGFV8pj122X3K9Nn-8AzqlnC3Q9rS70cjRie_1LeQ33RHKYivFIyiPAu4KFSFTuELNXu_1PsJJ4ZFWvu_1wdIXYv0HUP8onky0IfCiRBeAt7w1szUs0Y8kX1UqHCvwsX34bsjtxDP-kG1VcKRWhTUt1plzDt1cypXgJduhIbQ6u-bMeWQtR2asfC6QozBFiMR8JQQ-PidsR6yeKbCZd3v3SKa4a6GSgtezL4SD_1floTihyB8Etd8CtjvLlP7qlevTXFaBhUbqojODxHI9kbm1_1wb_1ipKoEz3t2zgRX1PWbOq71xGDAox_1TzqRo5EFBxgcLPF2JyuCJPCDF2tjTpRw3a0C6B1Mr9Q_1zl9TEJyyRURxJKE8g-UnTrS0mWR_1HbaWNdfnoQsJ4h0uKJ5IkW-xreRN0Xrn10xv7QKmnsXWpKotZlkcAzDv4Q5TBiF7yL63z_1IcjsM7tuT2qkGYPID4ActD9M-a81C3pkzSD6aqSBRAXb26gO5LP1w8erhSOVH69EVayXW4Lvs0Khz3e-90YYvns3-PbaAzvl2Xkj1XrtOKq-tidRQ6yxNIDsoHQlMamLkYREm1ylmAxki2BsrLPOK9OgYvjLzWwt54MOW3ydYb3CysLQZz5Di0usuqY84Qvx83tgBrwPdTcMAMGTVJANuGt7xL24qwGAsLMlW9c8QWPghZJ3BrQa-_1rUffBR_1lSY1UNCsOuKpXWDnMPEqV9kvgoye2lj9Zaw-QC-Sg_1FflyuuDcud7hudYZAOllb1aChYY_1CFuM85e7olqnratuoB5fK8beSZEAJOuiouuea-QY7ySC-rEn8cC5IUZW-q9-krUAhz9vOoJXqMo0zG9RvdFeJW1vAwUV2_1pBkpoYvcuf5tUwvj4L4zuBaumt3Ar8qcyfDsZdhxrK1ROwj4h86TqQJg532mT7S4Cnbekt4QvB9PcDPzJOCIql9xDq8JkCDst8kNWAIfNg_1Z6ifsK-UiygWYBTcra0x716lWIPjND_1VHIvgDReP7z_18F2DrJChsaiL-JkfAKvMhVY1OrpvEwsblg78aQM97MKknaIfrRMUiYI8h9YQ_1vvNuiwTl5R_1JYAcY3vCFLOzQIBJjKBqCDoxM_1TKtEoCerfoaa88JqgKmm9k6Sub0py5Iv6FT3XS0xK7jLZ7rZ-MRm2lafU7oUDzZgBJEm81RuWBLxm11Io5fiOdv-AYDh7MTDtZODkGLFXqrZUA8MVzBoxN-JXoEOqo8gV8sKcpaa0OXdjHoAtgQWm6nUEDgWBzEwUCKVuXcjnhUEJsT3YF5o2X2j4ki-DYP4u09VJ2Hq7odhznsN4KW-QRMuSfZtR4QT3RbKPnicQFDiQ_1ZUBPiAsHLmEzCdDd8xoiuX5t2gQsNjkTqlV35jnlk-85Qbg7gJVt_1Xs3tsWGnDxiySP2JO1) or [based on the bike's name](https://www.google.ca/search?q=cannondale%20scalpel%20900%20&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSiwEaiAELEKjU2AQaBAgDCAoMCxCwjKcIGl8KXQgDEidCoAKfAqMGsQeiBqEG0AKkBpkDkiCiIcMrrSGhIdsmriHaJt8i3SYaMHbjA1hN6L6RmKmbYibU5XLPtjscVTbjECTj_1treT0nzMcpIlFgJ0C9jhYjRJOGq_1QwLEI6u_1ggaCgoICAESBGd4nKEM,isz:l&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ2A4oA2oVChMIg-aj1b7ZxgIVwpMeCh3zFADL&biw=1920&bih=1075#tbm=isch&q=cannondale%20scalpel%20900).

Here is what I found :

- [Lefty white and blue](http://www.victorsbikes.byethost13.com/cannondale/scalpel2000.jpg)
- [Lefty white and red](http://www.bikesdetails.info/bikes/img/274-large.jpg)
- [Hi res lefty white, but suspension is different](http://images.evanscycles.com/product_image/image/ee7/62d/a7f/52522/cannondale-scalpel-carbon-1-2011-mountain-bike.jpg)